# Is there a downside to leaving client_max_body_size unchecked on Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I'm using Nginx on Ubuntu 16.04.

When uploading a file to one of my websites today, I ran into a `413 entity too large` error. In order to fix this, I set `client_max_body_size` to a higher value, which solved the problem.

I was just wondering whether there is any downside to setting this value to a very high limit (say `500M`), or leaving the size unchecked entirely?

Comment: Someone may upload a file so large that you run out of memory or disk space.

Answer (score 0):

Remember You need to configure both nginx and php to allow upload size.
Find you php.ini and just check on this parameter

```
;This sets the maximum amount of memory in bytes that a script is allowed to allocate
memory_limit = 32M

;The maximum size of an uploaded file.
upload_max_filesize = 2M

;Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file upload. To upload large files, this value must be larger than upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 3M
```

And then restart both php and nginx.
Also check your nginx error log,if there is something like

```
denying upload as opening to temp-file for upload failed: /xxx/xxx/xxx
```

Then its your permission file

Comment: But I'm not using PHP...